# CSS formatting of unordered list to wrap around images?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Any ideas how I can better format this HTML unordered (or ordered) list to better wrap around this left-floated image?

I keep coming across this fairly minor issue, but it does look bad on client's websites:
[image: left floated image and unordered list]

The image is using a right-margin, but it doesn't seem to apply to the ... or could I have the whole  as a block and not wrap it?

Any tips greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post some CSS code which is applied to your _list_

Answer (score 2):

You should position the list's bullets inside, instead of outside:

```
ul {
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Comment: Or simply set margin & padding values instead of assuming the browser defaults will work out.

Comment: This should be on the li n not the ul.